# Do mylar emergency blankets work through fabric?

Tags: thermodynamics, reflection

I was researching "self warming pet mats" like the one here: https://smile.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B003PTWS6W/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1515710243&sr=8-1-spons&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_FMwebp_QL65&keywords=self+warming+cat+bed&psc=1

From reviews and DIY sites on how to make your own, I have learned that these are basically a sheet of reflective Mylar encased in a fabric envelope.

My question is this: with the mylar inside the fabric pocket, is it really still able to reflect body heat back to the animal as advertised? I thought the shiny surface was part of what makes emergency blankets work...?

Answer (score 0):

The job of the shiny part is to reflect back infrared radiation so that it doesn't leave the system. The fabric part will either block the infrared radiation (so keeping its energy inside the system) or the radiation will pass through (and so the shiny part can do its job). So I don't see any reason having fabric over the Mylar would do any harm.